# patch consistently returns "Only garbage was found in the patch input"

Tags: diff, patch

**Background:**

```
[2021-07-14 23:00:25]» diff -v
diff (GNU diffutils) 3.6

[2021-07-14 23:04:05]» patch -v
GNU patch 2.7.6

[2021-07-14 23:04:20]» pwd
/home/chb/code/work/bar/baz/master
```

I'm in a directory that's many levels above a file I'm patching. I'm usign the `-u` flag to `diff` in the hope that `patch` will read the file paths in the unified output and patch the file accordingly. Both files are text files, so I'm also using the `-a` flag.

**Problem:**
I've tried many combinations of flags and none seem to actually get `patch` to work:

```
[2021-07-14 23:06:48]❮ diff -au bck/foundation/modules/iam/main.tf ../bck_cluster/bck/foundation/modules/iam/main.tf > au.patch

[2021-07-14 23:13:40]» cat au.patch
--- bck/foundation/modules/iam/main.tf  2021-07-14 16:50:49.131517079 -0400
+++ ../bck_cluster/bck/foundation/modules/iam/main.tf   2021-07-14 16:39:47.122605198 -0400
@@ -38,7 +38,7 @@

 resource "google_project_iam_member" "bck_cloudsql_admin" {
   project = var.project_id
-  role    = "roles/cloudsql.editor"
+  role    = "roles/cloudsql.admin"
   member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.project_service_account.email}"
 }

[2021-07-14 23:15:35]» patch --verbose < au.patch  
Hmm...  I can't seem to find a patch in there anywhere.
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.

[2021-07-14 23:16:30]» pwd
/home/chb/code/work/bar/baz/master
```

Though I know it's not necessary to adjust the paths present at the top of the file, I'm ready to try anything:

```
[2021-07-14 23:16:19]» patch --verbose -p0 < au.patch
Hmm...  I can't seem to find a patch in there anywhere.
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.

[2021-07-14 23:16:26]» patch --verbose -p1 < au.patch
Hmm...  I can't seem to find a patch in there anywhere.
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

Maybe this situation requires a context diff and not a unified diff?

```
[2021-07-14 23:21:17]» diff -ac bck/foundation/modules/iam/main.tf ../bck_cluster/bck/foundation/modules/iam/main.tf > ca.patch

[2021-07-14 23:22:42]» patch --verbose < ca.patch            
Hmm...  I can't seem to find a patch in there anywhere.
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

After reading "NOTES FOR PATCH SENDERS" in the man page, I tried changing directories and then running `diff` and `patch` in the common parent directory of both paths. Same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I create the 10-line `au.patch` and run `patch <au.patch` it finds a patch (but not the file of course). `md5sum au.patch` gives `247b3a419702428b8cce4a4eaca58d90`.

Comment: Your comment prompted me to open up the patch file in vim. There are color control chars in the file. Hence patch thinking that it's "garbage

The key (in this situation) was to add `--color=never` to the `diff` call. Now the question is: why is `diff` generating color output by default? The man page says `--color=auto` is the default. What in the shell environment is it reading such that it thinks it should add color control characters?